# Privatemsg PDOException: SQLSTATE[22P02]

Tags: 7, privatemsg

i'm using Drupal 7.15 and latest Privatemsg. I set up access and sucessfully sent a message to a user. As user, i see notification "Messages (1 new)", but when i'm clicking on it, i got an error.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "user_3" LINE 4: WHERE (base.uid IN ('user_3')) ^: SELECT base.uid AS uid, base.name AS name, base.pass AS pass, base.mail AS mail, base.theme AS theme, base.signature AS signature, base.signature_format AS signature_format, base.created AS created, base.access AS access, base.login AS login, base.status AS status, base.timezone AS timezone, base.language AS language, base.picture AS picture, base.init AS init, base.data AS data FROM {users} base WHERE (base.uid IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0)) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => user_3 ) in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 196 of /home/www/www.devbros.net/htdocs/includes/entity.inc).